# Export SQL Server table without changing Column's datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table **A** has column with datatype `VARBINARY(MAX)`. When exporting it to Excel, the column's datatype is changed to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

Importing it back into a new server, column's datatype remains `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

My requirement is to copy a table without changing its datatype to another server.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are two different products. Which one are you using? (Remove tag for product not involved.)

Comment: generate sql scripts

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Are you trying to copy the table to different server or the same server

Comment: I'm trying to copy to a different server

Comment: You can directly try select * into newtable from oldtable

Comment: Why on earth are you using **Excel** to copy structure and data from one SQL Server to another? .....

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
Select * into <LinkedServerName>.<databasename>.<SchemaName>.<NewTableName>
from <SourceTableName>
```

but you have to create a linked server in your source DB Server.

or

You can extract data and DDL using SSMS Generate scripts

Comment: I have read-only to the server.
thats why i am trying to copy the table to my local server

Comment: You can script out the table using SSMS